# How to get value of field <id> from Neo4j database by neo4j.rb in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, neo4j, neo4j.rb

Which method has `neo4j.rb` to get value of `<id>` field from `Neo4j` database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends what you mean ;)

The Neo4j.rb project has two main gems: `neo4j` and `neo4j-core`.  If you're using the `neo4j` gem to create `ActiveNode` / `ActiveRel` objects in Neo4j, you can either use the `node_object.id` / `node_object.uuid` methods to get the UUID generated by the gem or the `node_object.neo_id` method to get the Neo ID generated by the database.  The gem generates UUIDs because Neo4j internal IDs can be recycled and so don't offer the best option for external references to nodes.  Keep in mind, though, that if you use the `id_property` method in a model this will change the behavior of IDs generated by the gem.

The `neo4j-core` gem allows you to make [Cypher](http://neo4j.com/developer/cypher-query-language/) queries directly and from there you can get whatever you want.  An example:

```
# Gets the Neo4j internal ID
Neo4j::Session.current.query("MATCH (n) WHERE n.name = 'Sue' RETURN ID(n)")
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It was very detailed and useful.